# Parameter count mismatch in Extension for System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Tags: parameters, count, mismatch

There error occurred when _sendMethod.Invoke. 
Do you know how to resolve this? there is C# code for this. It seems to work fine. however It doesn't work right in vb.net. I need to write VB.NET for this.

This is informtation about exception.

StackTrace:   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at PIPEmail.MailMessageExt.Save(MailMessage Message, String FileName)

Message: "Parameter count mismatch."

Data:{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

TragetSite:{System.Object[] InvokeArgumentsCheck(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)}

```
Public Sub Save(ByVal Message As MailMessage, ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim assembly As Assembly = GetType(SmtpClient).Assembly
    Dim _mailWriterType As Type = assembly.[GetType]("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter")

    Try



        Using _fileStream As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create)
            ' Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
            Dim _mailWriterContructor As ConstructorInfo = _mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, New Type() {GetType(Stream)}, Nothing)

            ' Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
            Dim _mailWriter As Object = _mailWriterContructor.Invoke(New Object() {_fileStream})

            ' Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
            Dim _sendMethod As MethodInfo = GetType(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)

            ' Call method passing in MailWriter
            **_sendMethod.Invoke(Message,
                               BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                               Nothing,
                               New Object() {_mailWriter, True},
                               Nothing
                               )**

            '_sendMethod.Invoke(Message, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing,
            ' Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
            Dim _closeMethod As MethodInfo = _mailWriter.[GetType]().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)

            ' Call close method
            _closeMethod.Invoke(_mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, New Object() {}, Nothing)
        End Using


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 3):

I added '**True**' IN the code below then it works.

_sendMethod.Invoke(Message,
                                   BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                   Nothing,
                                   New Object() {_mailWriter, True, **True**},
                                   Nothing
                                   )